# How to get all Sundays and Saturdays using Fullcalendar in angular

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

I am new to Angular full calendar, and I am trying to write code for getting all Sundays and Saturdays in a year range. Is there any code for this?

Comment: That's something you might do with a date library. FullCalendar is mainly just for displaying events.

Answer (score 0):

We can use "Date()" object of javaScript to find this solution. Here is the solution which i used in my case to find number of saturdays and sundays in an year.

```
  totalNumberOfDays = 0;
  totalNumberOfHolidays = 0;
  totalNumberOfSaturdays = 0;
  totalNumberOfSundays = 0;

calculateWeekends(year:number){

    var date = new Date(`January 1, ${year}`)
    var endDate = new Date(`December 31, ${year}`)

    for (var d = date; d <= endDate; d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)) {

      this.totalNumberOfDays++;
      if(d.getDay()==0){
        this.totalNumberOfSundays++;
      }else if(d.getDay()==6){
        this.totalNumberOfSaturdays++;
      }
    }
    this.totalNumberOfHolidays = this.totalNumberOfSaturdays+this.totalNumberOfSundays;

    console.log(this.totalNumberOfSaturdays)
    console.log(this.totalNumberOfSundays)
  }

calculateWeekends(2022)
```

Here in above code first i am accepting a year in which we have to find number of weekends(saturdays and sundays), with the help of Date() object i am creating a new date that start at 1st January and end at 31st December then i am applying for loop on each date and checking whether it is weekend or not if it is weekend i am increasing the count.

Hope this will help you.